# ArcGIS Javascript API using CMV - Tiled Map Service Popup

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer, tile-layer

Using ArcGIS Online webmaps, you can enable a popup for a tiled map service by selecting a feature layer either currently in the map, or providing a url to the feature layer service. I believe then the popup attributes for the tiled layer use the feature layer's attributes. Is there a way to do this using Javascript API? I am currently testing the CMV application but I need the popup option for a tiled layer. Here is the layer code in the CMV viewer.js file.

```
{
 type: 'tiled',
url: 'http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/cWzdqIyxbijuhPLw/arcgis/rest/services/Antelope_Areas/MapServer',
title: 'Antelope Hunt Areas',
options: {
          id: 'antelopeareas',
          opacity: 1.0,
          visible: true,
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this as a workaround. Add the layer twice, once as a tiled layer and once as a feature layer.

1. Publish the layer with feature access enabled.
2. Add the layer to CMV, as a type: feature.
3. If you don't want it to show, set `opacity:` 0
4. If you also want to hide it from the layer control, set the `layerControlLayerInfos` option to exclude: true.

   ```
   operationalLayers: [{
   type: 'feature',
   url: 'http://services1.arcgis.com/g2TonOxuRkIqSOFx/arcgis/rest/services/MeetUpHomeTowns/FeatureServer/0',
   title: 'STLJS Meetup Home Towns',
   options: {
       id: 'meetupHometowns',
       opacity: 0, //make this transparent
       mode: 1 //on demand
   },
   legendLayerInfos: {
       exclude: true //hide from layer controller
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the work around, but just messing around with different settings, I placed the type='dynamic' on my tiled service. Amazing, that the identify worked like a dynamic service, but was still drawing like my tiled service. 
I don't know if it is supposed to work, but it did, so I will go with it.

```
        {
  //this is a tiled service but to make identify work keep as dynamic. 
            type: 'dynamic',
            url: 'https: .....rest/services/Reference/CENSUS_Cache/MapServer',
            title: 'Census',
            options: {
                id: 'Census',
                visible: false,
             },
            identifyLayerInfos: {
                layerIds: [0, 1, 2]
            }
        },
```